# Can I replace my laptop screen with another one with a higher resolution?

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, hp-elitebook

I currently own a HP EliteBook 8530p laptop.

The screen resolution is 1280x800. This is way too low for my standards, so I'm considering ordering another laptop screen with a higher resolution (for example [this one](http://www.yallstock.com/laptop-screen-hp-elitebook-8530p-154-widescreen-wuxga-matte-p-8060.html), 1920x1200).

Problem is, I searched some forums and it seems some people succeed in replacing their laptop screen with another resolution, but some other people don't. The laptop just doesn't recognize the new resolution, they are forced into the original resolution.

My question is: will this work on my laptop?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/79130/different-resolution-laptop-display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will often depend on the graphics chip in your laptop. Replacing your screen with a replacement provided by HP should generally work, assuming your graphics chip supports the resolution you're moving to.

Another issue could be with the drivers provided by HP. A generic driver provided by ATI or Nvidia should be able to scale to the maximum resolution for your chip and monitor, but theoretically, HP could limit the maximum resolution supported within the graphics driver.

Comment: Tried it, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would not be to attempt this unless you have read success stories of your exact laptop being upgraded with a certain LCD.  If I could find success stories with certain hardware, I would make sure to aquire that exact hardware for the upgrade.  It is still a gamble either way, but you can be at least much more likely to have success using a configuration that has been successful before at least once.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is... sometimes.

I've done this with Dell Latitude D-series. This worked because Dell originally sold the particular laptop model with options of at least two different screen resolutions. I found the screen I wanted on eBay, designated for my particular model. It was an easy swap (especially since Dell provides very complete disassembly/reassembly instructions on their web site) and the new screen works perfectly.

I would not attempt it without similar circumstances.

Comment: I did the same with D600's and D610's :)

Answer (score 0):

The online litterature should have specifications provided by the company, especially for technicians servicing the screen. somewhere in the litterature provided with the laptop model number you may have:

Résolutions internes supportées : 
résolution : 1366 x 768 (internal video only that figure)

Modes vidéos externes maximum   Résolution maximum : 2,048 x 1,536 
Taux de rafraichissement maximum : 100 Hz
Résolution non entrelacé avec un taux de rafraîchissement maximum : 1,600 x 1,200