# Different resolution on laptop display

Tags: laptop, display

Some of you might have read my previous question "[Weird laptop display](https://superuser.com/questions/75617/weird-laptop-display-problem)", I've got another question regarding the same issue. I should've mentioned I went for higher resolution display. Instead of XGA display (1024x768 px) I went for SXGA+ (1400x1050 px).

Is there a difference between connecting XGA and SXGA+ display to laptop motherboard (different ribbon cable, inverter, etc.)
Thanks a lot

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/54481/can-i-replace-my-laptop-screen-with-another-one-with-a-higher-resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the manufacturer.  I was able to swap out the 1680x1050 w/ CCFL backlight display in my notebook with a 1920x1200 w/ LED backlight -- but I had to make sure the new panel would mate with the same inverter and cable.  My original panel was LG, but the replacement panel was a Samsung.  The model numbers and compatible replacement part numbers specified by the manufacturer made it easier finding panels that mate.  The 1920x1200 panel wasn't offered for my machine, but was a compatible Dell part.

The cable that comes off of the motherboard branches off in a Y-split, a smaller connector carrying power to the inverter, and a larger connector that goes to the panel itself carrying display data (LVDS).  Making sure the panel mates with your existing step is crucial.

Comment: The final resolution: The display resolution was supported and offered for this laptop by vendor. However I needed to get new cable from MB to display that supported this resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference should be the panel itself.

Screens of the same physical size usually have the same inverter, there is no way to know 100%, but usually they are the same.